# julia import package stored as variable

Tags: julia

is there a way to programmatically import modules, something like?

```
deps = [ "HypothesisTests", "Plots", "MLDataUtils", "ArgParse",
        "GraphViz", "Cairo", "CSV", "JLD", "FreqTables",
        "MLBase", "Compat"]

for dep in deps
    Pkg.add(dep)
    try
        import dep   # <-- how?
    catch
        try
           Pkg.build(dep)
        catch
           nothing
        end
    end
end

Pkg.update()
```

I'd appreciate any better approaches to what I am trying to do, i.e. deal with failed import/using.

Comment: alternative to `try import/using` is to check `Pkg.installed(dep)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way that I found to address this:

```
s = Symbol("CSV")
@eval(import $s)
```